# Where is the cron job?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I work with linux servers at my job. Previously there was an engineer that set up our PBX servers so that they send a call to  land line phone. It does it every hour. I have been looking for that script everywhere. I looked for daemon script also looked at the cron jobs using the following command:

```
sudo crontab -l
```

Unfortunately I could not locate it.

I get fire when I ask a question  I can research, but please understand that I have done the research thats why I am here to ask for help . Thanks!

Comment: What do you get when you run `sudo crontab -l` ? do you get `no crontab for root` ? when you run it without the `sudo` what happens ?

Comment: This is more of a serverfault question.

Comment: I see some cron scripts but not the one I am looking for

Comment: @Bot and Paulo Scardine - you can "close" this question and ask to migrate it to serverdefault

Comment: @alfasin already done. I was just letting the user know.

Comment: Please do not down vote it will make things more complicated

Comment: @user200900 maybe the cron-job is scheduled under a different user (not `root`) ?

Comment: And you know, if it's not there - there's always the option that it has been deleted...

Comment: If its not there then what would trigger this process hourly beside a cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to `/var/spool/cron` and look for the script in the resulting directory. Also check the contents of `/etc/cron.d` and `/etc/cron.hourly/`. Also the system-wide `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: I checked each directory I could not see it, If its not there then what would trigger this process hourly beside a cron

Answer (score 0):

Also look inside:

/etc/cron.hourly

Comment: also check the crontab file of each user in the system, may be is setup under a different user... just thinking